# Cant get text color to animate over a fade in (not on hover) in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get text to fade in but also flash another color once to highlight it. I'm using animate.css to fade in but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the color to animate as well. Basically I want the text to flash white and fade back to its original color when it loads. I'm out of ideas after trying different animate and keyframe code. Pardon the messy code, I'm still new at this. Thanks.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html"; charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
    />
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-footer">
            <div class="subText fade-color first animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">first</div>
            <div class="subText second animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">second</div>
            <div class="subText third animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">third</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --idle: grey;
    --active: white;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    color: var(--idle);
    background: black;
    padding: 100px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 38px; 
}

@keyframes fadeColor {
    from {
        color: var(--idle);
    } 
    to {
        color: var(--active);
    }
}

.header-footer {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.first:hover, .second:hover, .third:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--active);
}

.subText {
    margin-right: 40px;
    float: left;
    transition: color 1s;
}

.fade-color {
    animation-name: fadeColor;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.third {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.second {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.first {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

https://codepen.io/subklue/pen/oNWyzZG

Comment: Your codepen seems to work for me in Chrome, using version 92.0.4515.107. The text fades in upon load, and fades from gray to white on hover. Unless you want it to turn white at an instant upon hover?

Comment: I want to add a color fade on the fade in. The hover is fine, I just cannot figure out how to add a color fade to the text as it loads in. In an effort to make the text pop a little more as it comes into the field of view. I've tried making keyframe animations for it but it i cant seem to get it to work. Thanks for looking!